# android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, background-service, foreground-service

i have a mediaplayer java class that connect to service to show notification,

the service dose'nt stop except when user clicks the notification cancel button

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID).setShowCancelButton(true).build();
```

the cancel code is:

```
public void hideNotification() {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
        stopForeground(true);
    }
```

i have edit my code to start the foreground service in the first time the user choose an item to play,
also when the app is in the background the notification updated not start again.
check this code:

```
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S ){
    \\check if the app in background and the notification exist then update it
                        if(ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == Lifecycle.State.CREATED
                                && notificationManager != null){
                            StatusBarNotification[] notifications = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
                            for (StatusBarNotification notification1 : notifications){
                                if(notification1.getId() == NOTIFICATION_ID);{
                                    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
                                    Log.w("App", "Working in Background");
                                }
                            }
                        }else {
                            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
                            Log.w("App", "Working First Time");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
                    }
```

my manifests code:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

  <service android:name="com.app.example.playerservice"
                 android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"/>
```

i'm still getting this crash on my play console: ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException

is there any solution for that?

if i replace the service with Workmanager can this solve the issue ? i mean can i handle the notification buttons when using Workmanager?

Note: I have tested the app many times with android studio emulator and with my phone with android 12, and i didn't catch any error.